# building multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am trying to build a multi dimensional array with node.js using redis as the data source. I am however not doing it right.

the menuKey contains key containing a sorted set in redis, the sorted set contains values referencing other keys. e.g:

```
menu:main:sections contains ["menu:main:section1","menu:main:section2"]
menu:main:section1 contains ["option1", "option2"]
menu:main:section2 contains ["option1"]
```

the array I am trying to build:

```
[["option1", "option2"], ["option1"]]
```

This is the code I have but I am placing a callback wrong somehow?

```
function handleMenu(jsonrpc) {
  var params = jsonrpc['params'];
  var result = [];
  var sections = [];

  menuKey = 'menu:' + params['menu'] + ':sections';
  async.series([
      function (callback) {
        redis.zrevrange(menuKey, 0, -1, function(err, sections) {
          async.forEachSeries(sections, function(section, sectionCallback) {
            redis.zrevrange(section, 0, -1, function(err, items) {
              result.push(items); 
              sectionCallback();
            });
          }, callback);
        });
      }
  ], function() {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong, please advice.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is an object instead of an array, plus the syntax looks wrong...`["menu:main:section1": ["option1", "option2"]` ??

Comment: I'm pretty positive that I need a multi dimensional array. And yeah the syntax might be wrong, I'm new to this node.js thing. I'm trying to get array[0][0] = 'a', array[0][1] = 'b', array[1][0] = 'c'. if you get my drift.

Comment: If your index is a string, you need an object.  If your index is an implicit integer, you need an array. `{ "prop1" : [ index0, index1 ], "prop2" : [ index0 ] }` (quotes around property names are optional in this format)

Comment: well, what I want is a multi dimensional array, so I might need to use an int index. The reason I use zrevrange is that I want the "sections" to be in order as "ranked" in the sorted redis set and those "sections" should contain the "items" which are references to hashes also in ranked order. I want to return the order of the sections and items in each sections. I will be retrieving the hashes in calls later on.

Comment: A multidimensional array would look like `array = [ [ index0, index1 ], [ index ] ]`.  If you want to map `"menu:main:section1" -> 0` somehow, and `"menu:main:section2" -> 1` go for it. But if you want to say `array["menu:main:section1"][0] = "a";` then you're using an object on the outside, and an array as the value of the property. Objects also support int-based prop names, but will suffer a small string-cast (`0 -> "0"`) penalty in most engines, including V8.

Comment: What are you actually getting in `results`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems.

1. you need a javascript object instead of an array as your top level container
2. you appear to be overwriting your results at the end

Try this:

```
function handleMenu(jsonrpc) {
  var params = jsonrpc['params'];
  var result = {}; // THIS LINE IS DIFFERENT
  var sections = [];

  menuKey = 'menu:' + params['menu'] + ':sections';
  async.series([
     function (callback) {
         redis.zrevrange(menuKey, 0, -1, function(err, values) {
         sections = values;
         callback(); 
     });
  },
  function (callback) {
    async.forEachSeries(sections, function(section, cb) {
      redis.zrevrange(section, 0, -1, function(err, values) {
        result[section] = values;
        cb();
      });
    }, callback);
  }
  ], function() {
    // result = sections; // <--- DON'T DO THIS
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

In this case `result` will look like this:

```
{"menu:main:section1": ["option1", "option2"], "menu:main:section2": ["option1"]}
```

You don't need a two dimensional array. `sections` is an ordered index into `result`. You go through `sections` in order and use these keys to extract arrays which preserve your secondary order. Like so:

```
var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    section,
    contents;

for(i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
    section = sections[i];
    contents = result[section];
    for(j = 0; j < contents.length; j++{
        console.log(contents[j]);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If absolutely have to have a 2D array. Then declare a variable `i` (and set it to 0) at the top of `handleMenu` and use it instead of `sections`, like this:

```
result[i++] = values;
```

also, change the `result` declaration back to this:

```
var result = [];
```

Comment: I see now that I've been using results as a hashmap (or object) this was not my intention. I updated the question rewritten to be arrays. The issue still exists. I'm placing a callback wrongly?